# Angular2 with Stomp.js

Tags: angular, websocket, stomp

I'm looking for Stomp.js or similar libs. I not found working with angular2.rc6/final example or lib. How can I reaplace Stomp.js something else? 
In my previously project with Angular 1.X  I used Stomp.js with Sock.
I'm in stuck..

**UPDATE**

I tried with this example application but but without effect. This example is outdated.
https://github.com/sjmf/ng2-stompjs-demo

Comment: The project https://github.com/sjmf/ng2-stompjs-demo has been update to work with Angular 2 via `angular-cli`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using new version of angular2 CLI https://cli.angular.io/

**I would recommend** to use [STOMP-Over-WebSocket Service](https://github.com/devsullo/ng2-STOMP-Over-WebSocket) for angular 2

Install this npm packages

```
npm i --save stompjs
npm i --save sockjs-client
npm i --save ng2-stomp-service
```

In **typings.d.ts**

Add `stompjs` and `sockjs-client` module declaration

```
declare module 'stompjs';
declare module 'sockjs-client';
```

In **app.module.ts**

```
import { StompService } from 'ng2-stomp-service';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [StompService]
})
```

In **app.components.ts**

```
import { StompService } from 'ng2-stomp-service';

private wsConf = {
  host:'test.com'
}

constructor(stomp: StompService) {

  stomp.configure(this.wsConf);

  stomp.startConnect().then(() => {
    console.log('connected');
  });


}
```

source https://github.com/devsullo/ng2-STOMP-Over-WebSocket

Comment: This is a good solution.  It works with Spring WebSocket without security.  However, it does not work with Spring Security and Spring Security WebSocket.

Comment: How can we do if the application has not been created with angular CLI ?

Comment: What change with Angular 6?

Answer (score 3):

For a proper Angular2/4/5 type StompService using Observables please refer to https://github.com/stomp-js/ng2-stompjs. This library exposes entire functionality using rxjs Observables.

It has been reported to work with Spring over WebSockets with and without security.

There are sample apps for Angular2, Angular4 and Agular5 as well.